# PHP Array unique not working

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multi dimension array and it was working fine with PHP 5.2 and now it is not working with php 5.5.9. 
I debugged and find out that array_unique is not working .
This is my code

```
array_push($import, $importtime, $regions); 
    array_push($imports, $import);
$imports = array_unique($imports);

foreach ($imports as $imp)
{


}
```

When I print_r impots before array unique, it is showing correct data but when I do print_r after array unique, it is not showing the data.  Any idea?

Comment: Post your array structure array values and errors you were facing

Comment: Can you provide a replication case on the likes of https://3v4l.org/ ?

Comment: Show the code in foreach also

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Mk1mkFMf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-unique.php

PHP 5.2 did sort differently then current versions.

sort_flags
The optional second parameter sort_flags may be used to modify the sorting behavior using these values:

Sorting type flags:

- SORT_REGULAR - compare items normally (don't change types)
- SORT_NUMERIC - compare items numerically
- SORT_STRING - compare items as strings
- SORT_LOCALE_STRING - compare items as strings, based on the current locale.

So maybe its just that param you need:

```
$imports = array_unique($imports, SORT_REGULAR);
```

Comment: show us your array - before applying array_unique, 
`print_r($imports)` and update your question.

Comment: Thank you guys,
$imports = array_unique($imports, SORT_REGULAR); works fine for me